# Scientific notation in Base-16

Tags: code-golf, math, base-conversion, hexadecimal, floating-point

Input a scientific notation number (base 10), output scientific notation in base 16 (as defined below).

### Details

In scientific notation, all non-zero numbers are written in the form

$$ m \times 10^n $$

Where \$ n \$ is an integer, and \$ m \$ is a real number, \$ 1 \leq |m| < 10 \$.

Consider scientific notation in base 16.

$$ m \times 10^n = m' \times 16^{n'} $$

\$ n' \$ is an integer, and \$ m' \$ is a real number where \$ 1 \leq |m'| < 16 \$.

### Input / Output

Input a positive real number. You may also choice to input \$m\$, and, \$n\$ separately. For all testcase, -100 < n < 100.

Output the number in hexadecimal scientific notation. Could be a single string or two strings. Number \$m\$, and, \$n\$ should also be formatted as hexadecimal strings.

Output as `1.2E3E4` is not allowed due to ambiguous. (1.2E3×10<sup>4</sup>, or 1.2×10<sup>3E4</sup>) You have to use other notations. For example, `1.2E3E+4`, `1.2E3, 4`, `1.2E3&4`, `1.2e3E4`, `1.2E3e4`, `1.2E3P4`, `1.2E3⏨4`, `1.2E3*^4` are all acceptable.

### Testcases

```
m, n -> m', n'
1.6, 1 -> 1, 1
6.25, -2 -> 1, -1
1.0, 1 -> A, 0
7.257672195146994, 93 -> d.eadbeef, 4d
1.234567, 89 -> f.83e0c1c37ba7, 49
1, -99 -> 8.bfbea76c619f, -53
```

You output may be slightly different from given testcase due to floating point errors. But you should keep at least 4 hex digits precision, and \$1 \leq m' < 16\$.

### Rule

This is code golf. Shortest codes in each languages win.

Comment: @Noodle9 In `1.2E3E4`, the digit `E` and the exponential separator have the same case.

Comment: @Noodle9 The E in 1.2E3 is not an exponent, it is hexadecimal 14.  So in the examples n' is not 1.2*10^3 (1200), it is 1 + 2/16 + 14/16*16 + 3/16*16*16 (approximately 1.1804 decimal).

Comment: @2012rcampion Ahhhhh! **Now** it makes total sense - thanks! :D

Comment: Be good to add a negative testcase.

Comment: Since there are already some answers assume positive numbers. I'm going to restrict the input as positive integers. Sorry for any changes. I had updated the description which only require to handle positive numbers.

Comment: *Output as 1.2E3E4 is not allowed*  Easily fixed by using X as the exponentiation letter: 1.2E3X4 or 1.2X3E4.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>134 124</s>  121 bytes

Expects a float and returns an array of 2 strings.

```javascript
n=>([x,y]=(+(g=n=>s=n.toString(16))(n).replace(r=/[1-f]/g,1)).toExponential().split`e`,[x.replace(r,_=>r.exec(s)),g(+y)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY7NaoQwFIX3fYosEyaJxp/ELDLQRZ@gS5FOjDdikURUivP0VuiijJ3e3YHvO@d@2i@7uHmYVhZiB7s3ezBXXG/03hh8wb054mICX@P7Og@hx0ISggPhM0yjdYBnk9SC@SbpqSDk4N62KQYI62BHTPgyjcN6gxutt1@FfpjrzGEDhxdCaI8vd9KQ3cWwxBH4GHvsseASBHo8QlCSIEGReHmEJc9KYNlzmJ1pwdN/ql8pSk@wOqqVVJnQpSik1gXo/AfuONiuBfAUFd2fiSwvSqmg0qcJz6scUidcrlqrDlWfVWBaP/2u4q1vwSrppNDHKivz/Rs)

#### How?

We first convert the input to hexadecimal and save the result in the variable `s`.

For instance, `7.257672195146994e93` is turned into:

```
"deadbeef0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

We replace all non-zero hexadecimal digits with `1`'s:

```
"111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

We coerce this back to an integer and invoke the [`.toExponential()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toExponential) method:

```
"1.1111111e+77"
```

We split this string into `x = "1.1111111"` and `y = "+77"`.

We replace all `1`'s in `x` with the non-zero hexadecimal digits of `s` in order of appearance:

```
"d.eadbeef"
```

Finally, we convert `y` to hexadecimal:

```
"4d"
```

Below is another example with `6e-19`:

```
"0.000000000000000b116b7de48f008"
"0.00000000000000011111111111001"
"1.1111111111001e-16"
[ "1.1111111111001", "-16" ]
[ "b.116b7de48f008", "-10" ]
```

#### Commented

```javascript
n => (                       // n = input
  [x, y] =                   // x = mantissa, y = exponent
    (                        //
      +(                     // coerce to integer:
        g = n =>             //   g is a helper function converting its input ...
          s = n.toString(16) //     ... to a hexadecimal string saved in s
      )(n)                   //   invoke g with n
      .replace(              //   replace:
        r = /[1-f]/g,        //     r = regular expression to match the non-zero
                             //         hexa digits
        1                    //     replace all of them with 1's
      )                      //   end of replace()
    )                        //
    .toExponential()         // convert to exponential notation 
    .split`e`,               // split into [ x, y ] = [ mantissa, exponent ]
  [                          // output array:
    x.replace(               //   replace in x:
      r,                     //     use r a 2nd time to match the 1's
      _ => r.exec(s)         //     use r a 3rd time to get the next hexa digit
                             //     from s, this time taking advantage of the
                             //     stateful nature of RegExp
    ),                       //   end of replace()
    g(+y)                    //   convert y to hexadecimal
  ]                          // end of output array
)                            //
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 217 bytes

```js
f=
n=>/^-?0\./.test(n=n.toString(16))?n.replace(/^(-?)0(.0*)(.)(.*)/,(_,s,z,d,t)=>s+d+'.'+t+'e-'+z.length.toString(16)):n=n.replace(/(-?.)(\w*).?(.*)/,(_,s,d,t)=>s+'.'+d+t+'e='+d.length.toString(16)).replace(/0*e=/,"e+")
```

```html
<input type=number step=any oninput=o.textContent=f(+this.value)><pre id=o>
```

Output format is `-?[1-f]\.([0-f]*[1-f])?e[+-][1-f][0-f]*`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 181 bytes

```perl
sub f{($e,$x)=(0,10**pop()*pop);$x/=16,$e++while$x>=16;$x*=16,$e--while$x<1;join('',map{sprintf$_?'%x':'%x.',$x%16,$x-=$x%16,$x*=16}0..12)=~s,\.?0*$,,r,sprintf$e<0?'-%x':'%x',abs$e}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHbbuIwEH33V1jIKAmMnThXQgj0B9infStVlYDTzYpcFKfaVIj9dTopdLe7wg9HnnPmnBnZreqOweWiX3NanEymgA1WajogndmsbVrTGtFK2GCnMgSm5vNfP8qjYsMaa6RnV5rzG72Syc@mrE3DgCprT7rtyrov2PPGmA7GEkEYOGI6mgaeft7GlLMjhHSt9LeGndg4MwbQwadfrZyNwW8RBmS5Zup8edWKfle6Xy63Tadoj1edrsOEkOqNPoxliks82nzzuDtkvNiJp7n9Uj5h7LHs7V1tw2plGAmRIgQq6X@Hr6lEmoTCDYBy957KJZqd@@YMqEMiNEdh5Mo4kH4Yxz7Q2BvVg1DZIVeqAOofMMT1/CCMgC7if0IKsfCUs5d7L8ozlP2YjGPj@M7AhciLXGVRuA9ljLk88Agpms78eAvrRMa@6s1kFbAa2FYNLbBviFb6wJ6TP/L2pelRQLTS4tptXdVSm5Mv8gTo5EsMlrcPm1A65W6gKce16FR/NFZAWf3XQq8eTD5f3gE)

I think using `sprintf('%a',$x)` could make the answer much shorter, just not sure how.

Ungolfed:

```perl
sub f {
  my($m, $n) = @_;
  my($e, $x) = (0, $m * 10**$n);
  $x/=16, $e++ while $x >= 16;
  $x*=16, $e-- while $x <  1;
  return (
    join('',map{sprintf$_?'%x':'%x.',$x%16,$x-=$x%16,$x*=16}0..12) =~ s,\.?0*$,,r,
    sprintf($e<0?'-%x':'%x',abs$e)
  )
}
```

Test:

```perl
for my $test (map[/-?[\da-f\.]+/gi],split/\n/,<<''){
    1.6, 1                -> 1, 1
    6.25, -2              -> 1, -1
    1.0, 1                -> a, 0
    7.257672195146994, 93 -> d.eadbeef, 4d
    1.234567, 89          -> f.83e0c1c37ba7, 49
    1, -99                -> 8.bfbea76c619f, -53

    my($m,$n,$Mexp,$Nexp)=@$test;
    my($Mgot,$Ngot)=f($m,$n);
    my $testname = sprintf"  %-25s -->  %s", "$m, $n", "$Mexp, $Nexp";
    is("$Mgot,$Ngot", "$Mexp,$Nexp", $testname);
}
```

Output:

```perl
ok 1 -   1.6, 1                    -->  1, 1
ok 2 -   6.25, -2                  -->  1, -1
ok 3 -   1.0, 1                    -->  a, 0
ok 4 -   7.257672195146994, 93     -->  d.eadbeef, 4d
ok 5 -   1.234567, 89              -->  f.83e0c1c37ba7, 49
ok 6 -   1, -99                    -->  8.bfbea76c619f, -53
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <sup><s>62</s></sup> 61 bytes

```ruby
->x{'%x.%x,%+x'%[m=x/16**n=Math.log(x,16).floor,m%1*16**9,n]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcpNDoIwFATgPad4mwbFUm2B1rfAG3gCwgJNkQU/BiF5Bjh7lcBu5pvpx8fXlakLbzT5jAQjzk7ks6xJ6Sx1ELTpvRgqUXevA3Gpj6Ksu67nDZPBOiNv88VlHgBIoa3ka9JCJTZUfNPLruavRhslMZGxRowtRvtFRXGijb3i1m2I6OXCFs8KJphphvc4fKDMKIfF/QA)

Input is a (decimal) float. Output is in the form \$m',n'\$, where \$m'\$ has a maximum precision of 10 hex digits and \$n'\$ is always signed.

`'%x.%x,%+x'` is a shorthand form of `sprintf` syntax, which creates formatted strings for numeric output. The format specifier `x` converts its argument to hexadecimal and the `+` guarantees signed output (otherwise negative numbers would be output with two leading dots representing an infinite string of leading `ff`s). We do three conversions to hex: (i) the integral part of \$m'\$, (ii) the fractional part of \$m'\$ (`m%1`; multiplying by `16**9` is necessary because the fractional part is ignored by `sprintf`), and (iii) \$n'\$.

The solution makes use of some straightforward mathematical transformations. Let \$m'=16^{m''}\$, so that \$x\equiv m10^n=m'16^{n'}=16^{m''+n'}\equiv 16^y\$. Then \$y=\log_{16}x\$. We are told that \$n'\$ is an integer, hence we take \$n'=\lfloor y\rfloor\$. This is the only choice of \$n'\$ for which \$0\le m''=y-n'<1\$, and hence the only choice of \$n'\$ for which \$1\le 16^{m''}=m' < 16\$ as required.

To support negative inputs, add `.abs` in two places and another `+` in the format string, bringing the code to 70 bytes:

```ruby
->x{'%+x.%x,%+x'%[m=x/16**n=Math.log(x.abs,16).floor,m.abs%1*16**9,n]}
```

Answer (score 1):

## C(GCC), 32 bit float, <s>133</s> <s>129</s> 128 bytes

-4 bytes ceilingcat

```
m;e;s(float f){m=*(int*)&f;e=(m>>23)-127;m=(m&-1U>>9|1<<23)>>3-(e&3);printf("%x.%05xE%c%x",m>>20,m&-1U>>12,"+-"[e<0],abs(e/4));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5BboMwEEX3nAJZIrJT28UY7FhOkLrgCF21XYAZt5FKGgUWSGnOTg1qmmZjyW/enz@OvTs3TZ0F22P/@VUPsSfnbrfG@8OwJitvYYe7sswkYSLTtgu/FRPPZWm@xXYbcFlKhmEliT2eQsZjlIw8SYuxSlwyIjqHU/obEhlFDwy9wDZ9o3XTY3jMCbGXaYB@uPbT2H3Up3UM4xHcAC2Jz9F1d48TT1iJqCc2CheH9zqKcdKT1wOit6CNLlFX7w94XrFUCK5A0BiJSqAwXpjiWQEsWyi7YcHTRX2q0j@mg6qVzoQpRK6MycHIoLQc6rYB8FXe/stnMi@Uho0JiucbCakTTuqm1lVu7nqYmZ0Nb3wDtVZOCeMrVshZukw/)

This extracts the exponent and mantissa from a floating point number.  Since the maximum exponent is +/-127 in base 2 (approx 38 base 10), this doesn't quite meet the challenge since it fails on larger exponents. So...

## C(GCC), 64 bit float, <s>167</s> <s>163</s> 147 bytes

-4 bytes ceilingcat

```
long m;e;s(double f){m=*(long*)&f;e=(m>>52)-1023;m=(m&-1UL>>12|1L<<52)>>3-(e&3);printf("%lx.%013lxE%c%x",m>>49,(m&-1UL>>15)*8,"+-"[e<0],abs(e/4));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7NboMwEITvPAWyRGRTm2LMn@XEUg/ccu2p7QHMOo0EJApUQkrz7BSQ0rSXlXbmm5017GDMNDWn7uC2ClSP69NX1YBrybXd@XgxfLKxCna41TqJCONhJFQ7rxvGX/da8@ib77fb2dJaMAwbQdT5cuwGi5HXjIEXctGMhWe8EdH5RizpI5sQP6foiaE32IYftKx6DM8xIeo2DdAPv99Q13yWF9@F8QxmgJq4V@de0mPPEqYRtUQ5PV7m3XKx15P3DtFHUDk3py2PHV5OrB08SIFTF/GCo9letTSIEmDRqrKHzINwRV@K8FfLZjRLs4jLhMeplDFIMSN1AGVdAdgirv/kIxEnaQa5nBEb5AJCw43IqjIrYvmvh8mFyYPKVlBmqUm5tAVLxALdph8)

Comment: Suggest `(~e&3)` instead of `3-(e&3)`

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 192 bytes

```r
function(x,i=function(x,p=F,y=abs(x))`if`(y>0,{d=c(0:9,letters[1:6])[rev(y%/%(16^(0:log(y,16)))%%16+1)]
c("-"[x<0],d[1],"."[p],d[-1])},0))cat(i(x*16^(3-(n=log(x^2,16)%/%2)),T)," ",i(n),sep="")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZDNaoRAEITvPoUMCN1Ja6b9GTNLJsc8QW7GZV13DIKoqBFl2Wc3ettbFQVfFTVs12K0rKqmKyazVX9tOdVdCwvV5sn05otWU1xHWBAvdXWB9VPS/WZKkCdNjZ0mO4wZn1SO2WBnWL03D1id97jpfmElVojoeaxeGXOnBOGLbPmQOd0yzkkEIusP7XOOD5KIZTFBDcvLwYh8aM2BWc7hAdrZISJ9IwlXUA0t0mh7IwRuVTfA7NatW@7tJAOpwoRYUhqESarSkHXCsdI6tjoiDsIoTlRq3zWx9bVGdO7O0yEwo3MMET@tQOex/QM)

Happily handles negative numbers, even if now not required.

Commented:

```r
base16float==function(x,                                    
    l=c(0:9,letters[1:6]),                          # define hexadecimal digits
    i=function(x,point=FALSE,y=abs(x))              # create function to write hexadecimal integers
    `if`(x==0,0,                                    # if x is zero, just write zero
        {d=l[rev(y%/%(16^(0:log(y,16)))%%16+1)]     # otherwise get the digits for each power-of-16
            c("-"[x<0],d[1],"."[p],d[-1])})         # and paste them together with the sign
    )                                               # (and with a "." after the first digit if 
                                                    # specified by point=TRUE in the function call)
    cat(i(x*16^(3-(n=log(abs(x),16)%/%1)),T),       # so: first output the mantissa as a 4-digit integer
                                                    # with point=TRUE to include the dot,
        " ",                                        # leave a gap,
        i(n),                                       # and write the exponent
        sep="")
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>135</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>119</s></sup> 105 bytes

```python
def f(x):m,n=x.hex().split('p');m=hex(int('1'+m[4:],16)<<int(n)%4);return m[2]+'.'+m[3:],f'{int(n)//4:x}'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDdioMwFITv@xRBWGJoTBsTk8bWfZFuL/w5oYVqRS24FJ/dNbpQYdlzlZl8ZxKm/u6uj0qMYwEWWb8ncUmrpGdX6H3C2vp@63xcY3IsE2fdqklyvC3PMr5Qrsjp5KyKfEhybKB7NhUqz@Fli5mDxARZ/FqQ3U7G/YDHDtquRQnyN2ganzMFnCLf42y/Ho8ij3uE0AVTLIwgCP8BgxU5XS@B6V9u/8b0FKiVDrmJuFTGSDDCbRUM0iIDsO8tWazTQyEjpeFgHG3ZQcA@57nQWaoX2qxoCMzMHVhmM0i1yhU3dvlzJGaQbBrXxhN/PUMtc0zRcuQCk419NMgVRhH0NeQdulWzbuP5Adej9Z1BZl03ruupcmcNKPhEr3ZAr@Y8gclvxGXAZPwB)

Inputs a float.
Returns a tuple of strings \$(m',n')\$.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 284 bytes

`struct` approach. At least I tried)

```python
from struct import*
m=lambda s,c,n,k:[s[n:],'-'+s[k:]][c]
n=lambda s:m(s,s[0]=='-',2,3)
o=lambda s,x:m(s,x<0,0,0)
p=lambda x:x[2]+'.'+x[3:]
s=lambda x,y,d=2**52:(o(p(hex((x%d+d)*2**((x//d+1)%4)).rstrip('0')),y),n(hex(((x//d)%2048-1023)//4)))
f=lambda x:s(unpack('Q',pack('d',x))[0],x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/JboMwEIbP9VNwieyBYbHZAioP0bPlQ8qioBRjYSI5T0@tRE01h5l//k@zmMd@XXV@NttxTNu6BHbf7v0ezItZtz0kS/dzWb6HS2CxR423VlqpW4U0ppGVt1Yp2Sui31S7MItWZqrrPIICcyDr/wz39N1nhj6AmD/HtU4KFdGERk7mrSL27eADh06EYSlatjLDrqNjzJ2GaIDQt32dpkPE4VQAJJs/fzaMZhQAH4D6hT8ZOImsOMc8EzmkqaeBTP/7Lbtrc@lvjH5RfBUDRQfgf/HpcJ3kSTVyrBJRjrFAnmRe1V7VVS14U/KiappibHKMeSLyoqzq8dx4McZNo8i0bsEczNrvIh9mm/XOJjYDHL8)